# Emit message from callback. Express.io node.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

HELP please!!

Im using socket.io to be able to route my sockets.
The problem i having is that in my regular POST callback i need to emit the result to a group

```
req.io.room(room).broadcast('task', req.body)
```

but since its a regular post method io object dosent exists.

i tried to use Route Forwarding like this

```
exports.callback = function(req,res){
 req.io.route('emitTask')
};

exports.emitTask= function(req){
   req.io.room(room).broadcast('task', req.body);
};
```

but io object dosent exists there.

My routing looks like this.

```
app.post('/callback/:customer/:id', socket.callback);
app.io.route('emitTask', socket.emitTask);
```

Does anybody have any suggestion how to solve this issue.

//K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `io` object as a result of something like:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

You need to somehow reach that object to be able to do something like:

```
io.sockets.in(room).emit('emitTask');
```

You could make it available as a singleton:

```
// sockets.js
var io = ...;

exports.sendRoom = function (room, message) {
  io.sockets.in(room).emit(message);      
};

// routes/index.js
var sockets = require('./sockets');

app.post('/callback/:customer/:id', function (req, res) {
  sockets.sendRoom('myroom', 'emitTask');
  res.send(200);
});
```

A more scalable solution would be to introduce a bus in your app: a global event emitter that dispatches events across modules:

```
// bus.js
module.exports = new require('events').EventEmitter();

// sockets.js
var bus = require('./bus'),
    io = ...;

bus.on('sendRoom', function (room, message) {
  io.sockets.in(room).emit(message);      
});

// routes/index.js
var bus = require('./bus');

app.post('/callback/:customer/:id', function (req, res) {
  bus.emit('sendRoom', 'myroom', 'emitTask');
  res.send(200);
});
```

Comment: I added socket.js to deal with the room as you describe.
It works, but for some reason i get two meessage back to the clients when i broadcasting to the room.

    Room1
     -client1 (gets two messages)
     -cleint2 (gets two messages)

Comment: Can you log to see if you're calling `io...emit` twice ? Maybe you are subscribing to an event twice.

Comment: Duplicate messages solved by using namespaces instead of rooms.